# PySpark Stream - Check if the combination of columns exists in another dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I have a data frame with the following schema:

| Name | Timestamp | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2020-04-01T11:50:46.2470092Z | 3.0 |
| B | 2020-04-01T11:50:46.2470092Z | 2.1 |
| A | 2020-04-01T11:50:48.2470092Z | 2.7 |
| C | 2020-04-01T11:50:48.2470092Z | 2.5 |

I have stream of data that has the smae schema as that of the data frame. If the stream contains a row that does not exist in the dataframe (same Name and Timestamp, value does not matter), its should be written to ADLS. Rows that exist (copies), can be discarded. What is the best way to check if a row in my stream exists in the dataframe?

Comment: Use a semi-join? like `stream.join(df, stream.columns, 'semi')`. not sure if this works with streams

Comment: I was able to perform this in batch mode using the left_anti join but I cannot do this in streaming mode as I get 'Left semi/anti joins with a streaming DataFrame/Dataset on the right are not supported;' message.